Can I see my completed quests in No Man's Sky?
In the menu I can see my active missions from the Log tab, but is there a way to see my completed quests?
I don't really care about the secondary ones, but I'd like to know which main quests I've completed so far (I started this save years ago...)
Are they listed somewhere?
